# How to increase each 'SAL' column value by 100 (100, 200, 300,... and so on)?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, rownum

I have a task where I need to increase each row value under 'SAL' by a 100. Starting with the first entry and up to the last one.

I have written the code to select the proper entries and sorted them, but cant find a way to increase the values of a 'SAL' column.
I am using https://livesql.oracle.com/ sandbox to try and learn SQL

```
SELECT ROWNUM, T1.*, T2.DNAME, T2.LOC
FROM SCOTT.EMP  T1, SCOTT.DEPT T2 
WHERE T1.DEPTNO = T2.DEPTNO
AND DNAME = 'SALES'
AND JOB NOT LIKE 'MANAGER'
ORDER BY HIREDATE DESC
```

The last line is not working

```
SET SAL = SAL + (ROWNUM * 100)
```

Comment: `update emp set sal = sal + 100`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
UPDATE (
   SELECT ROWNUM AS R, T1.*, T2.DNAME, T2.LOC
   FROM SCOTT.EMP  T1
      JOIN SCOTT.DEPT T2 ON T1.DEPTNO = T2.DEPTNO
   WHERE DNAME = 'SALES'
      AND JOB NOT LIKE 'MANAGER'
   ORDER BY HIREDATE DESC)
SET SAL = SAL + (R * 100);
```

Instead of `ROWNUM AS R` you can also use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY HIREDATE DESC) AS R` (then you don't need the `ORDER BY HIREDATE DESC`)

Comment: @Radas `ROWNUM` is generated before the `ORDER BY` clause is applied; as a result, this is not going to correlate the increase with the `hiredate`. Oracle will read the rows in a whatever order makes sense to it (typically the order the rows are found in the data files but could equally be more random on a parallel system) and then applies `ROWNUM` in the order it read the rows and only then orders the rows.

Comment: `ROWNUM` with `ORDER BY` may yield unexpected results @Radas . Btw, `UPDATE` through inline view shouldn't contain an analytic function such as `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Answer (score 0):

`ROWNUM` with `ORDER BY` may yield unexpected results, since those are generated before `ORDER BY` in the processing steps of a SELECT statement. So, prefer using `ROW_NUMBER()` function for your `UPDATE` operation ( `UPDATE` through inline view shouldn't contain an analytic function such as `ROW_NUMBER()`. As a result you cannot use your current method, but use the one below ) :

```
UPDATE EMP e 
   SET e.SAL = nvl(e.SAL,0) + 
               (
                SELECT SAL_ADD 
                  FROM
                  ( SELECT 100 * ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY HIREDATE DESC) as SAL_ADD, 
                           T1.EMPNO 
                      FROM EMP T1
                      JOIN DEPT T2
                        ON T1.DEPTNO = T2.DEPTNO
                     WHERE DNAME = 'SALES'
                       AND JOB NOT LIKE 'MANAGER'
                    ) tt
                 WHERE e.EMPNO = tt.EMPNO );
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=baddc30f5708bc0f7c7ef6e761e4ccbe)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Ohh! This answer is accepted but let me give another thought for it - `MERGE INTO`

```
MERGE INTO SCOTT.EMP  T11
USING (SELECT T1.EMPNO , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T1.HIREDATE DESC) as RN
         FROM SCOTT.EMP  T1 JOIN SCOTT.DEPT T2 
          ON (T1.DEPTNO = T2.DEPTNO)
       WHERE DNAME = 'SALES'
         AND JOB NOT LIKE 'MANAGER') T22
ON (T11.EMPNO = T22.EMPNO)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET T11.SAL = T11.SAL + (RN*100);
```

Cheers!!